# How can I find a list of all the commands for Dev Console?

Tags: pc, battlefield-3

In the Dev Console of Battlefield 3, is there an official list of all the commands/cheats that can be achieved through the in-game developer console in the PC Version? So far i've seen only Render.showFPS true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came across a list of console commands while Googling. Please note, it's not from an official source and the list is so large that it made no sense to paste it all here:

http://www.battlefield3online.com/some-useful-battlefield-3-console-commands/2991/#post13111

There's an alphabetized list of the commands here:

http://pastebin.com/X8erNDpH

Top level categories are

```
Ai
AILocoComp
AimAssist
Aiming
AIProximityReactionsComp
Ant
antDebug
AntDriven
AntMemory
ANTRagdoll
AwardCounter
Awards
BFServer
Blaze
BreakableController
BreakableModel
BugManager
CameraManager
Character
ChaseCamera
Client
ClientDynamicModel
ClientLadderComponent
ClientMeleeEntity
ClientMeleeWeapon
ClientMetrics
ClientStaticModel
Collision
ColorCorrection
Commerce
CompositeMeshEntity
Core
CpuTiming
CrashDump
CustomizeInput
DebrisSystem
Debug
DebugCamera
DebugMenu
DebugMenuCameraUtil
DebugMovie
DebugRender
Decal
Demo
DestructionVolume
DogTags
DriverComponent
dumpArenaMap
dumpMemPages
DynamicAvoidance
Effect
EffectManager
Enlighten
Entity
EntityFrustumCull
EntityGrid
EntityGridQuery
EntityGridRenderQuery
Explosion
FreeCamera
FriendlyFire
FriendZone
Game
GameAnimation
GameMode
GameReport
GameSpline
GameTime
GameWorld
get
GoalCover
Gunsway
Heightfield
HitReaction
Input
ITK
Jamming
jobhandler
JobTiming
Juice
Keybindings
LanServerBackend
Level
Login
main
Melee
Memory
MemoryDisplay
Mesh
MultiProfiler
Network
Occlusion
Online
Pathfinding
PathFollower
PerformanceTracker
Persistence
Physics
PhysicsDebug
PhysicsRender
PhysicsVisualDebugger
Pickup
PickupEntity
Player
PlayerUtils
PointSystem
PostProcess
presenceTest
print
ProfileOptionsManager
profiler
proximityHook
RagdollComponent
RagdollEntity
Raycasts
Recoil
Render
RenderDevice
ResourceManager
RigidMeshEntity
Sequencer
server
ServerAdmin
ServerAdministrationLog
ServerAwardSystem
ServerBackend
serverDestruction
ServerMapSequencer
ServerMeleeWeapon
ServerMetrics
ServerPerformanceTracker
set
settings
ShaderSystem
SharedDataManager
SmokeManager
Snowroller
Soldier
SoldierBoundsChecker
SoldierRender
SoldierTest
Sound
SpatialQueryManager
SpecialMoves
specialMovesCheck
Spotting
StaticCamera
Stats
storage
StreamManagerMessage
SubLevel
SupportedCornerShooting
SupportedShooting
SyncedBFSettings
SyncedGame
Terrain
TerrainStreaming
TestPoints
Tickets
TimingView
TransactionLog
TransactionTransmitter
TurboLoader
UdpSocket
UI
ui3dLaserTagComp
UIConnectionComp
UICoopComp
uiHud
uiNametagComp
UnlockComponent
Vars
VegetationSystem
Vehicle
VehicleDeployWeapon
VeniceOnline
VeniceUI
voiceRouter
Voip
WarpAnimationEntity
Weapon
WeaponFiring
Weapons
web
Window
WorldRender
```

Hope this helps.